# Facebook Connect Asp.net C# Request Cookies Returning Null

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I was able to login into my website and successfully register new user using facebook connect and get the user information.

But, all of a sudden it stopped working.

code on the aspx page

```
  <div id="fb-root"></div></form>

<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: '147340123456789', // App ID
        channelUrl: '', // Channel File
        status: true, // check login status
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
};

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function (d) {
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
} (document));
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears all of the code that does login is missing from that page.  Check your source control for a previous version.